# Windows services and setting them to disable

Tags: windows, service, nt

Is there a way for an application to get notified that a specific service is set to disabled?
I have a NT service and I want to "catch" this event and keep that time for later use.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You want notification when the setting changes? Are you prepared to poll?

Comment: sure. What does that involve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ought to be able to do something in WMI to do with that. I think that you can subscribe to the `__InstanceModificationEvent` notification for the particular instance of `Win32_Service` that you're interested in.

On the other hand, if someone's going to stop and disable the service, they'll just stop and disable the process monitoring it. So you're not going to win, anyway.

Why don't you just secure the service ACL so that only Administrators can stop and disable it? This is, in fact, the default anyway. And if the user's got admin privileges, you've already lost.

Comment: +1 Indeed, why re-invent the wheel? Windows has plenty of security control nowadays, just use it!

Comment: I was going to suggest using RegNotifyChangeKeyValue() on the service's registry key, but I like your solution better.

Comment: I just want to get notified, I do not want to prevent anything.

Answer (score 0):

other parts of my client app will poll and call RegNotifyChangeKeyValue to see if the service is disabled, it is I will make note of it...